# Is there a theory stronger than ZFC in consistency but does not prove its consistency?

Tags: logic, set-theory, incompleteness

A theory $T$ in the language of set theory is stronger than another theory $T'$ in consistency if consistency of $T$ implies consistency of $T'$. If $T$ is able to formalize finite arguments, proves the consistency of $T'$ and does not prove its own consistency, then $T$ has to be stricly stronger than $T'$. (The above is from [Kunen, *Set theory*, 2011](https://fa.ewi.tudelft.nl/%7Ehart/onderwijs/set_theory/Jech/Kunen-1980-Set_Theory.pdf), paraphrased in my language)

But every theory stricly stronger than $\mathsf{ZFC}$ that I have found proves consistency of $\mathsf{ZFC}$! For example, $\mathsf{MK}\vdash\operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ where MK is the Morse-Kelley, and $\mathsf{ZFC}+\phi\vdash\operatorname{Con}(MK)$ where $\phi$ says that there is an inaccessible cardinal. Is there a set theory $T$ such that
$$S\vdash\operatorname{Con}(T)\implies\operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$$
$$S\not\vdash\operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})\implies\operatorname{Con}(T)$$
but $T\not\vdash\operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ (where $S$ is a metatheory that is either of $\mathsf{PA}$, $\mathsf{PRA}$, $\mathsf{ZFC}$)?

Edit: as pointed out in Toby's comment, the second condition $\operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})\not \implies\operatorname{Con}(T)$ may not properly deliver the requirement that $T$ and $\mathsf{ZFC}$ should not be equally strong. Kunen's textbook mentions intuitionistic logic, so maybe this condition should be interpreted there somehow.

Second edit: I have restated conditions above within a metatheory $S$, as suggested in Toby's comment.

Comment: Do you really mean to require $ \neg \bigl ( \operatorname { Con } ( \mathsf { Z F C } ) \implies \operatorname { Con } ( T ) \bigr ) $?  Because this simply means $ \operatorname { Con } ( \mathsf { Z F C } ) \; \wedge \; \neg \operatorname { Con } ( T ) $.  In other words, you're assuming that $ \mathsf { Z F C } $ is consistent and $ T $ is not.  And since $ T $ is inconsistent, then of course $ T \; \vdash \; \operatorname { Con } ( \mathsf { Z F C } ) $.

Comment: @TobyBartels Oh, I haven't thought about that! I wanted to exclude those theories equiconsistent to $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Now that $\lnot(\operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})⟹\operatorname{Con}(T))$ doesn't express this, I wonder what does...

Comment: My first thought was to have $T$ add something that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ does not resolve, like $CH$.  Unfortunately (for this), we have a proof that $\mathsf{ZFC}+CH$ is consistent iff $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is.  We need to add something that might make $T$ inconsistent.

Comment: @RossMillikan One difficulty is the way we usually know things have higher consistency strength than ZFC is because they imply large cardinals in inner models, but since Con(ZFC) is absolute that means they must imply Con(ZFC) outright.

Comment: The problem is that as far as we know, all of these theories are consistent; the ones that we know to be inconsistent are, for that very reason, uninteresting.  And if they're all consistent, then they're all equiconsistent.  So you have to look at something relative like $\mathsf{PA}\;\vdash\;\operatorname{Con}(T)\implies\operatorname{Con}(T')$ and $\mathsf{PA}\;\nvdash\;\operatorname{Con}(T')\implies\operatorname{Con}(T)$ (where $\mathsf{PA}$ is Peano arithmetic, but you could weaken this to primitive recursive arithmetic $\mathsf{PRA}$, strengthen it to $\mathsf{ZFC}$ itself, or so on).

Comment: @TobyBertels Thanks for the suggestion! I have restated the second condition using $\not\vdash$, not $\not\implies$.

Comment: This is just an idea, but would something like $\mathrm{ZFC} + \neg \mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{ZFC} + \varphi)$ where $\varphi$ says there exists an inaccessible cardinal works?

Comment: @DavidGao Nope: any reasonable metatheory will prove that $\mathsf{ZFC}+\neg Con(\mathsf{ZFC}+\varphi)$ is consistent iff $\mathsf{ZFC}$ itself is, for any choice of $\varphi$ whatsoever (the point is that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is equiconsistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}+\neg Con(\mathsf{ZFC})$, and $\neg Con(\mathsf{ZFC}+\varphi)$ is implied by $\neg Con(\mathsf{ZFC})$ no matter what $\varphi$ is).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ah yes, you’re right. I messed things up in my head. Should have tried something like $\mathrm{ZFC} + \neg \mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{PA} + \mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{ZFC}))$ instead.

Comment: Ah wait, no, that seems also equiconsistent with $\mathrm{ZFC}$. Just ignore my comment.

Comment: @TobyBartels I feel that my question needs further clarification. To me, the condition $T\not\vdash\operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$ seems to imply $\operatorname{Con}(T)$, $\mathsf{PA}\vdash\operatorname{Con}(T)$, and finally $\mathsf{PA}\vdash\operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC})$. Do I need to replace this with something like $\mathsf{PA}\not\vdash(T\vdash\operatorname{Con}(\mathsf{ZFC}))$? This does not seem to affect validity of Noah's proof.

Comment: If $ T \nvdash \operatorname { Con } \mathsf { Z F C } $, then $ T $ must be consistent, but that doesn't mean that $ \mathsf { P A } $ can prove this, and it certainly doesn't mean that $ \mathsf { P A } $ can prove $ \operatorname { Con } \mathsf { Z F C } $ (which is false, following Gödel, if $ \mathsf { P A } $ is consistent, since $ \mathsf { Z F C } $ is an extension of $ \mathsf { P A } $).

Comment: That said, if you have a $ T $ such that $ T \nvdash \operatorname { Con } \mathsf { Z F C } $, then (if $ \mathsf { P A } $ is sound, which Noah's proof assumes anyway) it's also true that $ \mathsf { P A } \nvdash ( T \vdash \operatorname { Con } \mathsf { Z F C } ) $.

Comment: @TobyBartels Sorry to @ you twice (I have deleted my previous comment which was a mess, so I'm not sure you are notified). I still don't get what the gap between $\operatorname{Con}(T)$ and $\mathsf{PA}\vdash\operatorname{Con}(T)$ is. What I had in mind is a vague argument: we now have a particular proof of $\operatorname{Con}(T)$, and $\mathsf{PA}$ is able to reenact (?) this proof to conclude that $\mathsf{PA}\vdash\operatorname{Con}(T)$.

Comment: First of all, $\mathrm{Con}\,T$ could be true if nobody ever proves it. It's true if, when you write down a list of symbols constituting a valid argument from the axioms in $T$, the list never concludes with a contradiction. Since that's a statement about infinitely many (finite) things, we might never prove it, even if it's true. So even assuming $\mathsf{PA}$ is sound (so it proves only true statements), $\mathsf{PA}\vdash\operatorname{Con}T$ is different from $\operatorname{Con}T$, not only because it says a proof can be formulated in $\mathsf{PA}$ but because it says a proof exists at all.

Comment: (Whether infinitary statements can *really* be true or false, independently of our proving them, is a question for the philosophy of mathematics; but even if you take the attitude that the only *true* things are those that we've proved in, say, $ \mathsf { Z F C } $, there's still a difference between $ \operatorname { Con } T $ and $ \mathsf { P A } \vdash \operatorname { Con } T $, because there's a difference between $ \mathsf { Z F C } \vdash \operatorname { Con } T $ and $ \mathsf { Z F C } \vdash ( \mathsf { P A } \vdash \operatorname { Con } T ) $.)

Comment: @TobyBartels Thank you so much! I thought I have a particular proof of $\operatorname{Con}(T)$ using Theorem 4 of Hamkins's article in Noah's answer, and that this should also work in $\mathsf{PA}$. But the proof of Theorem 4 at least uses some of model theory, and I guess that's why I can't prove $\operatorname{Con}(T)$ in $\mathsf{PA}$ in the same way. As for Noah's proof that there exists such a $T$, I don't even know whether the existence of a theory can be stated in $\mathsf{PA}$ .

Comment: Generally speaking, theorems in proof theory can be formulated in $ \mathsf { P A } $, and even in $ \mathsf { P R A } $, because they amount to statements about recursive operations on finite lists of symbols, which can be coded as natural numbers.  Their proofs, however, are another matter!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a fun nonconstructive argument that such a theory - indeed, an extension of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ by a single sentence - must exist (for an actual example of such a sentence, apply Theorem 4 of [Hamkins, *Nonlinearity in the hierarchy of large cardinal consistency strength*](https://jdh.hamkins.org/wp-content/uploads/linearity-2.pdf)):

Let's fix our metatheory $S=\mathsf{PA}$, and suppose the answer to your question was negative. In particular, this means that for any sentence $\varphi$, if $\mathsf{PA}\not\vdash Con(\mathsf{ZFC})\rightarrow Con(\mathsf{ZFC}+\varphi)$ then $\mathsf{ZFC}+\varphi\vdash Con(\mathsf{ZFC})$. Let's abbreviate $Con(\mathsf{ZFC})\rightarrow Con(\mathsf{ZFC}+\varphi)$ by $\varphi^-$, and let's abbreviate $\varphi\rightarrow Con(\mathsf{ZFC})$ by $\varphi^+$. Then - rewriting the above implication as a disjunction and doing a bit of $\vdash$-juggling - this means that **for any $\varphi$ whatsoever** we have $$\mathsf{PA}\vdash\varphi^-\quad\mbox{or}\quad \mathsf{ZFC}\vdash\varphi^+$$ (or both). Say $\varphi$ is "type $1$" if the first disjunct holds via a proof shorter than any witnessing the second disjunct, and that $\varphi$ is "type $2$" if the second disjunct holds via a proof shorter than any witnessing the first disjunct. Note that by brute-force-searching we can computably tell the type of any sentence $\varphi$.

Under mild soundness assumptions, if $\varphi$ is type $1$ then $\mathsf{ZFC}+\varphi$ is consistent and if $\varphi$ is type $2$ then $\mathsf{ZFC}+\neg\varphi$ is consistent. But it's a standard exercise to show that there is no algorithm which, on input a sentence $\varphi$, can pick one of $\varphi$ or $\neg\varphi$ which is guaranteed to be consistent with $\mathsf{ZFC}$. So we have a contradiction.

Of course it would be nice to have an actual example of such a sentence! With enough work the above argument can in fact be turned into such an example, but Hamkins' argument cited above is a better way to get such an example.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's so interesting that there is an indirect proof via a computability argument.